# Slider in css not working when trying to show 6 slides

Tags: html, css, slider

I am trying to adapt a pen from codepen that i found but it doesn't seem to work. The pen is a text slider with 3 slides and my goal is to make it work with 6 slides. 
The original codepen is  [this](https://codepen.io/nucliweb/pen/ymedj) 
My pen is [this](https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/rvMvYm)

The problem that i think it is is that i got the percentage wrong in my code. My code for 6 slides is

```
@keyframes anim-1 {
0%,
4.15% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
4.15%,
12.45% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
16.66%,
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
0%,
16.66% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
20.75%,
29.17% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
33.32%,
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
0%,
33.32% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
37.47%,
45.83% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
49.98%,
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
 0%,
49.98% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
54.13%,
62.43% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
66.58%,
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes anim-5 {
0%,
66.58% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
70.73%,
79.03% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
83.18%,
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes anim-6 {
 0%,
83.18% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
87.33%,
95.85% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

I messed up the indentation here in this post but everything should be clearer in the codepen. 
I don't think that i made any typos and i am still thinkin what could cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, you're not separating the different classes with a comma. Add these, and it will work.

**Your Code**

```
.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3
.item-4
.item-5
.item-6 {
...
```

**The Fix**

```
.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5,
.item-6 {
...
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5,
.item-6{
 position: absolute;
  display: block;
 top: 2em;
  
  width: 60%;
  
  font-size: 2em;

 animation-duration: 20s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
 animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2{
 animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3{
 animation-name: anim-3;
}

.item-4{
 animation-name: anim-4;
}

.item-5{
 animation-name: anim-5;
}

.item-6{
 animation-name: anim-6;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
 0%, 4.15% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  4.15%, 12.45% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  16.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
 0%, 16.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  20.75%, 29.17% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  33.32%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
 0%, 33.32% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  37.47%, 45.83% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  49.98%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
 0%, 49.98% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  54.13%, 62.43% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  66.58%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-5 {
 0%, 66.58% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  70.73%, 79.03% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  83.18%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-6 {
 0%, 83.18% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  87.33%, 95.85% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<p class="item-1">This is your last chance. After this, there is no turning back.</p>

<p class="item-2">You take the blue pill - the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe.</p>

<p class="item-3">You take the red pill - you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit-hole goes.</p>

<p class="item-4">You take the red pill - you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit-hole goes.</p>

<p class="item-5">You take the red pill - you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit-hole goes.</p>

<p class="item-6">You take the red pill - you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit-hole goes.</p>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg81cL5n/)**